# Load balancing is not working properly

Tags: docker, load-balancing, kubernetes, internal-load-balancer

We want to test kubernetes load balancing. So we create a 2 node cluster thats runs 6 replicas of our container. Container has running apache2 server and php and it will print pod name if we browse hostname.php

**Cluster details:**
172.16.2.92 -- master and minion
172.16.2.91 -- minion

**RC and service details:**

frontend-controller.json:

```
{
   "kind":"ReplicationController",
   "apiVersion":"v1beta3",
   "metadata":{
      "name":"frontend",
      "labels":{
         "name":"frontend"
      }
   },
   "spec":{
      "replicas":6,
      "selector":{
         "name":"frontend"
      },
      "template":{
         "metadata":{
            "labels":{
               "name":"frontend"
            }
         },
         "spec":{
            "containers":[
               {
                  "name":"php-hostname",
                  "image":"naresht/hostname",
                  "ports":[
                     {
                        "containerPort":80,
                        "protocol":"TCP"
                     }
                  ]

               }
            ]
         }
      }
   }
}
```

frontend-service.json:

```
{
   "kind":"Service",
   "apiVersion":"v1beta3",
   "metadata":{
      "name":"frontend",
      "labels":{
         "name":"frontend"
      }
   },

   "spec":{
      "createExternalLoadBalancer": true,
      "ports": [
        {
          "port":3000,
          "targetPort":80,
          "protocol":"TCP"
        }
      ],
      "publicIPs": [ "172.16.2.92"],
      "selector":{
         "name":"frontend"
      }
   }
}
```

**Pod details:**
frontend-01bb8, frontend-svxfl and frontend-yki5s are running on node 172.16.2.91
frontend-65ykz , frontend-c1x0d and frontend-y925t are running on node 172.16.2.92

If we browse for 172.16.2.92:3000/hostname.php, it prints POD name.

**Problem:**

Running watch -n1 curl 172.16.2.92:3000/hostname.php on node 172.16.2.92 gives only that pods(frontend-65ykz , frontend-c1x0d and frontend-y925t ). They are not showing other node 172.16.2.91 pods.
Running same command on node 172.16.2.91 gives only that pods. They are not showing other node 172.16.2.92 pods. 
Running same command outside of cluster showing only 172.16.2.92 pods.
But we want to see all pods not specific node pods, if we run wherever.

Check below details for more information and help you if anything wrong

# kubectl  get nodes

```
NAME          LABELS                                           STATUS
172.16.2.91   kubernetes.io/hostname=172.16.2.91   Ready
172.16.2.92   kubernetes.io/hostname=172.16.2.92   Ready
```

# kubectl get pods

```
POD              IP            CONTAINER(S)   IMAGE(S)                                         HOST                      LABELS                                                              STATUS    CREATED          MESSAGE
frontend-01bb8   172.17.0.84                                                                   172.16.2.91/172.16.2.91   name=frontend                                                       Running   About a minute
                               php-hostname   naresht/hostname                                                                                                                               Running   About a minute
frontend-65ykz   10.1.64.79                                                                    172.16.2.92/172.16.2.92   name=frontend                                                       Running   About a minute
                               php-hostname   naresht/hostname                                                                                                                               Running   About a minute
frontend-c1x0d   10.1.64.77                                                                    172.16.2.92/172.16.2.92   name=frontend                                                       Running   About a minute
                               php-hostname   naresht/hostname                                                                                                                               Running   About a minute
frontend-svxfl   172.17.0.82                                                                   172.16.2.91/172.16.2.91   name=frontend                                                       Running   About a minute
                               php-hostname   naresht/hostname                                                                                                                               Running   About a minute
frontend-y925t   10.1.64.78                                                                    172.16.2.92/172.16.2.92   name=frontend                                                       Running   About a minute
                               php-hostname   naresht/hostname                                                                                                                               Running   About a minute
frontend-yki5s   172.17.0.83                                                                   172.16.2.91/172.16.2.91   name=frontend                                                       Running   About a minute
                               php-hostname   naresht/hostname                                                                                                                               Running   About a minute
kube-dns-sbgma   10.1.64.11                                                                    172.16.2.92/172.16.2.92   k8s-app=kube-dns,kubernetes.io/cluster-service=true,name=kube-dns   Running   45 hours
                               kube2sky       gcr.io/google_containers/kube2sky:1.1                                                                                                          Running   45 hours
                               etcd           quay.io/coreos/etcd:v2.0.3                                                                                                                     Running   45 hours
                               skydns         gcr.io/google_containers/skydns:2015-03-11-001                                                                                                 Running   45 hours
```

# kubectl get services

```
NAME            LABELS                                                              SELECTOR           IP(S)           PORT(S)
frontend        name=frontend                                                       name=frontend      192.168.3.184   3000/TCP
kube-dns        k8s-app=kube-dns,kubernetes.io/cluster-service=true,name=kube-dns   k8s-app=kube-dns   192.168.3.10    53/UDP
kubernetes      component=apiserver,provider=kubernetes                             <none>             192.168.3.2     443/TCP
kubernetes-ro   component=apiserver,provider=kubernetes                            <none>             192.168.3.1     80/TCP
```

# iptables -t nat -L

```
Chain KUBE-PORTALS-CONTAINER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
REDIRECT   tcp  --  anywhere             192.168.3.184        /* default/frontend: */ tcp dpt:3000 redir ports 50734
REDIRECT   tcp  --  anywhere             kube02               /* default/frontend: */ tcp dpt:3000 redir ports 50734
REDIRECT   udp  --  anywhere             192.168.3.10         /* default/kube-dns: */ udp dpt:domain redir ports 52415
REDIRECT   tcp  --  anywhere             192.168.3.2          /* default/kubernetes: */ tcp dpt:https redir ports 33373
REDIRECT   tcp  --  anywhere             192.168.3.1          /* default/kubernetes-ro: */ tcp dpt:http redir ports 60311

Chain KUBE-PORTALS-HOST (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             192.168.3.184        /* default/frontend: */ tcp dpt:3000 to:172.16.2.92:50734
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             kube02               /* default/frontend: */ tcp dpt:3000 to:172.16.2.92:50734
DNAT       udp  --  anywhere             192.168.3.10         /* default/kube-dns: */ udp dpt:domain to:172.16.2.92:52415
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             192.168.3.2          /* default/kubernetes: */ tcp dpt:https to:172.16.2.92:33373
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             192.168.3.1          /* default/kubernetes-ro: */ tcp dpt:http to:172.16.2.92:60311
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because flannel is not working properly so do

> /root/kube/reconfDocker.sh on everynode

it will restart the docker and flannel then check the ifconfig docker0 and flannel0 bridge IPs should be in same network. Then load balancing will work. It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me problem is in networking configuration.
Pods in host 172.16.2.91 has IP address 172.17.0.xx which maybe accessable form the other host, i.e. 172.16.2.92

If ping fail, then please check your networking against kubernetes requirement:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/networking.md
Kubernetes imposes the following fundamental requirements on any networking implementation (barring any intentional network segmentation policies):
•all containers can communicate with all other containers without NAT
•all nodes can communicate with all containers (and vice-versa) without NAT
•the IP that a container sees itself as is the same IP that others see it as